# Remover espaço em branco php

Tags: php, html, formulário

Ao digitar os valores (um por linha), exemplo:

```
    valor1
    valor2
    valor3
    valor4
```

Ele irá retornar: valor1,valor2,valor3,valor4

entra_valores.php

```
    <html>
    <body> 
    <form action="junta.php" method="post">
    <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="valores">
    </textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Pronto" />
    </form>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

junta.php

```
    <?php
    $valores = $_POST['valores'];
    $quebra = explode("\n", $valores);
    $junta = implode(',', $quebra);
    $valores = preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $junta);
    echo $valores;
    ?>
```

Comment: Qual é a entrada que você está colocando? Se for os quatro valores, um em cada linha, seu código fica ainda mais confuso. Você quebra a string nos \n, junta tudo, remove todos os espaços em branco e no final substitui os espaços por vírgula? Neste ponto não existirão espaços para serem substituídas por vírgulas e o seu resultado fica 
 `valor1valor2valor3valor4` ([link](https://repl.it/@acwoss/LawngreenCookedWeblogsoftware)). Tem certeza que é este o código que está rodando? Se sim, por favor, faça um [mcve] demonstrando o problema - pode ser no repl.it ou ideone.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, se quiser remover TODOS os espaços em branco, você pode usar uma expressão regular.

```
$valores = preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $_POST["valores"]);
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu precisava. Obrigado.